# for Loop impeding me from retrieving data from Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to retrieve data from Firebase to populate the screen with the user's `myID`, `userID`, and `imageURL` that's unique for each user. I have the following method `readMessage();` which is what retrieves that information from the database, but it isn't working properly.

This is what the **Logcat** tells me `Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.e.chatapp.Model.Chat`.

At first I tried to get rid of the `for Loop` because in the past that made it work fine, but this time it hasn't helped. Can someone indicate what the error is in my code?

Problem is the `if` statement.

Below you have my `MessageActivity.java` and Model class `Chat.java`.

[image]

**MessageActivity.java**

```
private void sendMessage(String sender, String receiver, String message) {

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    hashMap.put("sender", sender);
    hashMap.put("receiver", receiver);
    hashMap.put("message", message);

    reference.child("Chats").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(hashMap);
}

private void readMessage(final String myID, final String userID, final String imageURL) {
    mChats = new ArrayList<>();

    mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
    mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mChats.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myID) && chat.getSender().equals(userID) ||
                        chat.getReceiver().equals(userID) && chat.getSender().equals(myID)) {
                    mChats.add(chat);
                }

                mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mChats, imageURL);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

**Also tried it like this**

```
 private void readMessage(final String myID, final String userID, final String imageURL) {
        mChats = new ArrayList<>();

        mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Chats");
        mReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mChats.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Chat chat = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);
                    if (chat.getReceiver().equals(myID) && chat.getSender().equals(userID) ||
                            chat.getReceiver().equals(userID) && chat.getSender().equals(myID)) {
                        mChats.add(chat);
                    }

                    mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(MessageActivity.this, mChats, imageURL);
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Chat.java**

```
public class Chat {

private String sender;
private String receiver;
private String message;

public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message) {
    this.sender = sender;
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.message = message;
}

public Chat() {
}

public String getSender() {
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) {
    this.sender = sender;
}

public String getReceiver() {
    return receiver;
}

public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
    this.receiver = receiver;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the attributes in the database don't match the fields in the `Chat Pojo` class.

The attributes in the database should be all lowercase same as the `Pojo` so you can map the class to the database.

Also your database should be like this:

```
 Chats
     randomId
         message : "hi"
         reciever: "peter"
         sender  : "jmb"
```

This way the `randomid` will act as an object and inside that object you have the 3 attributes that are in your `Chats` class also.

Comment: Okay, so I should change my HashMap so that all of the attributes are lowercase? And that's it?

Comment: And add a random ID using push()

Comment: Why do I need to add a random ID? Isn't it okay the way I have it now in the database? I just updated the picture so you get a better idea of how everything is being stored.

Comment: The randomId will act as an object that is mapped to the class, currently u are retrieving message of type string and not of type Chat

Comment: I just uploaded the **MessageActivity.java** with the HashMap to do what you're saying, but now the messages instead of being saved are becoming overwritten. Did I do it wrong? Also, I updated the picture so you can see how it's turning out now.

Comment: Instead of child(firebase.getUid()),u can use `push()`

Comment: Ah okay, gotcha. The randomID is a chat ID not the userID, okay. I was thinking it was the userID. So push(). is to set a randomID for the task?

Comment: Yes the push() is a method that creates a random ID, you can use it to separate the data in firebase.